# How can I skip the root password prompt when installing mysql-server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, packages, apt

I am writing a bash script that involves installing the `mysql-server` package on Ubuntu. The package interactively asks the user for the root MySQL password desired, however this is not good for me as I want the script to be fully automated without user involvment.

Is it possible to skip the password prompt, and manually set the root password using another method?

Comment: Check [this question and my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/567792/is-it-possible-to-install-software-without-asking-for-a-password/567800).

Comment: @gronostaj That's not what I am referring to. I mean the interactive prompt that forces you to type in a MySQL root password.

Comment: See this question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202347/how-can-i-pass-a-password-from-a-bash-script-to-aptitude-for-installing-mysql